# Visual Studio: Design time build failed for project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, intellisense

I recently moved a C++ VS project from desktop computer to my laptop.

However when I open the solution, it gives me this error:

```
error : Designtime build failed for project 'C:\Coding_Projects\C++\Taxi\Taxi.vcxproj' configuration 'Debug|x64'. IntelliSense might be unavailable.

Set environment variable TRACEDESIGNTIME = true and restart Visual Studio to investigate.
```

Is there any suggestions on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Is there any suggestions on what I could do to fix this? - How about: Set environment variable TRACEDESIGNTIME = true and restart Visual Studio to investigate.

Comment: How did you move it?  Some of the information in the project files will be specific to each computer.

Comment: Most likely you need to install something that is missing from your portable, if you follow the advice from visual studio you may be able to find out what is missing.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I compressed the folder on my desktop into a ".rar" file and then moved it onto my computer.

Comment: The some of project files contain paths which are local to each computer.  If you have SDKs, external components in different places on each computer you will have to edit these files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys.

The issue was the Visual Studio and QT on my desktop were updated to the latest versions available however my laptop's VS and QT were not up to date.

So all I had to do was update my Visual Studio and QT on my laptop, and then in the QT Project settings: Change the "Installation" to my updated version of QT (msvc2019_64).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when cleanning solutions before rebuild,  in my case was because of repeated entries (Configurations and Config properties) in some of my .vcxproj files.

I cleaned them manually, and it was gone.